# Bigcommerce API PHP library will not create a customer with custom form_fields

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I'm using the Bigcommerce php library to create customers through the API, which works fine, but I get `{"status":400,"message":"The field 'name' is invalid."}` back when I try adding the `form_fields` array of objects to the call. Is it possible to include these in a createCustomer call?

Here's basically what I'm trying to do:

```
$customer_object = array(
    "email" => $email,
    "first_name" => $first_name,
    "last_name" => $last_name,
    "_authentication" => array(
        "password" => $password
    )
);
$form_fields = array();
if(!empty($occupation)) {
    $obj = (object) array("name" => "Occupation", "value" => $occupation);
    array_push($form_fields, $obj);
}
$customer_object["form_fields"] = $form_fields;
$response = Bigcommerce::createCustomer(json_encode($customer_object));
```

Also, here's what a Bigcommerce customer record looks like:

```
Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\Customer Object
(
    [ignoreOnCreate:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
        )

    [ignoreOnUpdate:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
        )

    [fields:protected] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 34
            [company] => Company Name
            [first_name] => John
            [last_name] => doe
            [email] => email@example.com
            [phone] => 123-456-7890
            [date_created] => Tue, 19 Jul 2016 23:40:14 +0000
            [date_modified] => Wed, 10 Aug 2016 17:39:28 +0000
            [store_credit] => 0.0000
            [registration_ip_address] => 
            [customer_group_id] => 6
            [notes] => 
            [tax_exempt_category] => 
            [reset_pass_on_login] => 
            [accepts_marketing] => 
            [addresses] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [url] => https://example.com/api/v2/customers/34/addresses.json
                    [resource] => /customers/34/addresses
                )

            [form_fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Occupation
                            [value] => Developer
                        )
                )

        )

    [id:protected] => 34
    [ignoreIfZero:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [fieldMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form_fields are currently GET only and they are only available in stores with a specific "store experiment" turned on. This has been omitted from our documentation, so we will work on updating that to provide better clarity.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply. I emailed you. Hopefully making POST available is on your radar as this would enable a lot of great possibilities for more robust customer accounts.

Comment: yeah, POST and PUT are definitely on the to do list. We wanted to make the ability to read available as soon as possible rather than wait to have them all done.